# How to display Interstitial ad when opening new Fragment?

Tags: android, popup, admob, ads, interstitial

I created navigation bar with three tabs.
I want that if I click on the second tab a Interstitial Ad pops up.

I already tried it with this code in my second Fragment:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout,container,false);

        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("MYID");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
```

But the problem here is that the Ad pops up with a delay from 5 seconds and this is why I recieved a warning mail from AdMob that I have to change my Interstitial ad.

So how can I do that the Interstitial Ad pops up directly?

Comment: preload the ad first - do .loadAd in advance of the user opening. and set a flag which is then used to run .show - but bear in mind that if the user will naturally be pressing on the screen after clicking the second tab you may still get a warning from admob

Comment: @MStoner Thank you, can you explain how to set a flag? So first I do .loadAd in my MainActivity onCreate and then ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show Interstitial ad correctly in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141684/how-to-show-interstitial-ad-correctly-in-this-case)

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is set SetOnClickListener on Ads itself instead it should be set on table layout of viewpager2.

```
// Register page change callback here        
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(onboardPageChangeCallback)

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, onboardViewPager) {
            tab, position ->

}.attach()
```

and your onboardPageChangeCallback

```
var onboardPageChangeCallback = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            if (position == 1) { // 0 index position
              // Add you interstitial load code here  
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: hope it helps you now if anything else ask