# How can I set the Interstitial Ad when the fragment change?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

I have a navigation bar with three tabs/fragments and I want that if I click on the second tab that the Interstitial Ad pops up without any delay. 
How can I archieve that?
Where do I have to .loadAd the Ad and where do I have to .show it?
Please describe it in detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show Interstitial ad correctly in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141684/how-to-show-interstitial-ad-correctly-in-this-case)

Answer (score 0):

LoadAd at your MainActivity startup and show on fragment transaction.