# How do I display the Interstitial Ad?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

I have a navigation bar with three tabs each tab is a fragment.
Now I want that if I click on the second tab, that the Interstitial Ad pops up.
So where do I have to .loadAd the Ad? And where do I have to .show the Ad?

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public MediaPlayer mp;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    public InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();



        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getContext());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9756227769488050/2954649723");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


    }
```

My secondFragment:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout,container,false);


        return rootView;
    }
```

And (I dont know if that matters) my TabFragment:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */
            View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         *Set an Apater for the View Pager
         */
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        /**
         * Now , this is a workaround ,
         * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
         * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
         */

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                   }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {

            if(position == 0){
                return new FirstFragment();
            }
            if(position == 1){
                return new SecondFragment();
            }
            if(position == 2){
                return new ThirdFragment();
            }

        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "first";
                case 1 :
                    return "second";
                case 2 :
                    return "third";
            }
                return null;
        }
    }


        });
    }

}
```

So where do I have to say `showInterstitial()` ?

```
final public void showInterstitial(){
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
        }
```

Im hanging on that problem for over a month now, so please give me a explanation in detail. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show Interstitial ad correctly in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141684/how-to-show-interstitial-ad-correctly-in-this-case)

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the load() in the main activity like you did so it will start caching the ad. Then you will call the showInterstitial() function where you handle the adapter click event, i.e. where you do handle the fragments.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Android, where do I handle my Fragments? ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    // Insert the Ad Unit ID
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-123456789/123456789");

    //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


}
public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edited answer & call `displayInterstitial()` on click of second tab