# How can I display my Interstitial by clicking on a new tab?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

in my MainActivity onCreate im loading the Interstitial Ad like this:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("MY ID");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And I also have this code in my MainActivity:

```
    public void displayInterstitial() {

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now if I try to say `displayInterstitial();` in my fragment onCreateView like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lustiges_layout,container,false);

    displayInterstitial();


    myGridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView3);
    myGridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(getActivity(), items3));

    return rootView;
}
```

It says "cannot resolve methood 'displayInterstitial()'" 
How can I show my Interstitial Ad when the Fragment opens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show Interstitial ad correctly in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141684/how-to-show-interstitial-ad-correctly-in-this-case)

Answer (score 0):

If `MainActivity` is parent activity of your `fragment` on which you want to call `displayInterstitial();` method then you can do it in this way.

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).displayInterstitial();
```